# default text-align for th in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

## Question

Why do `th` elements have centered text when `text-align: center;` is not specified by browser default?

## System setup

- MacBook Pro, mid-2014
- OS X v 10.10.2
- Google Chrome v 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit)
- all software up-to-date as of time of this posting

## Example Code

```
<!-- no external or internal CSS applied.
     browser default styles only. -->
<table width="500" border="1"> <!-- attributes for debugging only. never use these attributes in real code (use CSS instead). -->
    <tr><th> table heading </th><th> centered text     </th></tr>
    <tr><td> table data    </td><td> left-aligned text </td></tr>
</table>
```

## Screen Shots

HTML rendering:
[image: screen shot of Google Chrome's rendering of a sample table. the text in the th elements is aligned center while the text in the td elements is aligned left.]

Dev Tools on first `th` element:
[image: screen shot of Google Chrome Developer Tools showing browser-default styles applied to a th element. th{font-weight:bold;} td,th{display:table-cell;vertical-align:inherit;}/*inherited from table*/table{border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:2px;border-color:gray;}]

Nowhere here do I see `text-align: center;`, yet clearly the text in `th` is center-aligned. Is this a Chrome bug?

## Related Question

[<th> text-align compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321065/th-text-align-compatibility)

## Update

**As of Chrome v67, `th` now has a specified `text-align: -internal-center;` by browser default.**

Comment: I'd guess that `<th>` appears that way by default because (as far as I'm aware) there's no requirement for it to be anything else according to the HTML specification. **EDIT:** In fact, [this W3 page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) suggests that the default style for `<th>` should be `{ font-weight: bolder; text-align: center }`

Comment: I'm aware that [HTML recommends `th` elements appear centered and bold](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.2). What I'm not aware of is how Google Chrome renders it that way without `text-align: center;` in the CSS. However I do see `font-weight: bold;`, as shown in my screen shot.

Answer (score 4):

I have now posted a new answer to the [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321065/th-text-align-compatibility/28307524) mentioned. I hope it clarifies the situation, but since this question isn’t really a duplicate but a specific question about browser behavior, I include the relevant point here:

Chrome (and Firefox) implements `th` elements in special way, which is not consistent with any specifications, including the “suggested rendering” in HTML5, even though it *often* leads to the same results. Effectively, there is no browser default style sheet rule for `th`, but when normal CSS cascade has been applied and it does not result in any value for `text-align` for `th`, then magically the value `center` is assigned to it (instead of the initial value of `left` as per the specs). This is probably a holdover from old pre-CSS days when `th` was simply centered.

If you inspect, in dev tools “Computeted” tab, a `th` element in a table that has no CSS settings, there is no value shown for `text-align`, even though the content is actually centered. If you check the “Show inherited properties” (which thus means more than the name says), you can see `text-align: center`.

Comment: This seems like a very odd way of doing it. Why doesn't Chrome just use normal CSS, like it does with the `caption` element? (`text-align: -webkit-center;`)

Comment: Chrome is not alone; Firefox does the same thing.