# text-align: left and start behaving differently with direction left-to-right

Tags: css, text-align

Given the following HTML document containing a table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        /* text-align: left; */
      }
      th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 1 Column 1</th>
        <th>Row 1 Column 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will show a 2x2 table, where the contents of the first row are centered, and the contents of the second row are left-aligned. This is due to the user-agent stylesheets, which on chrome sets `text-align: -internal-center;` on `th` elements, and does not set an alignment for `td`-elements, so that these use the default left-alignment.

[image: A 2x2 table, where the contents of the first row are centered, and the contents of the second row are left-aligned]

If we uncomment the `text-align: left;` styling for the `body` element in the code snippet above, the `th`-elements will inherit this style from the `body`-element, and all the contents of the table will be left-aligned.

However, if we change it to `text-align: start;`, the first row will be centered again. How can that be? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align?retiredLocale=de#values), the values `start` and `left` should behave identical if the direction is `ltr` (left-to-right), which is the case since we put `dir="ltr"` on the `html` element.

Using `text-align: end` or `right` both shifts the contents to the right, while using `left` shifts the contents to the left. The only value which does not work is `start`.

I see this behaviour on both Firefox and Chrome, on MacOS.

Note that I am not asking for workarounds, but want to understand why this happens!

Comment: Checking this Chrome dev tools, in the "Styles" tab it still shows `text-align: -internal-center;` as the style for the `th` elements, and whatever value `text-align` on body has, is crossed out. On the "Computed" tab however, the computed value is the same as on body for every of the values other than `start`, when it explicitly becomes `left`.

Comment: _"According to MDN, the values start and left should behave identical"_ - they do, if you set them for the `th` elements directly. Looks like a side effect of that `-internal-center` value to me, but I couldn't say if there was any intention behind it, or it is basically just a bug.

Comment: @CBroe The behaviour is the same in FF, the user agent value is `text-align: -moz-center-or-inherit;`. Reading the W3C Docs, it seems to be a bug but the fact all browsers behave the same seems to indicate some sort of intention. Hard to say what is going on exaclty.

Answer (score 2):

Source: W3C > HTML5 > Rendering > The CSS user agent style sheet and presentational hints > [Alignment](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/rendering.html#alignment) (the last paragraph in the section):

> User agents are expected to have a rule in their user agent stylesheet that matches `th` elements that have a parent node whose computed value for the 'text-align' property is its initial value, whose declaration block consists of just a single declaration that sets the 'text-align' property to the value 'center'.

In other words, user agents should center `th` only if the default value of its parent is unchanged. `text-align: start` is the default value in current browsers, therefore `th` gets centered.

I was able to come to this conclusion thanks to a question posted in 2011 [`<th>` text-align compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321065) and [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28307524)

Comment: Thanks for your answer  Totally worth the bounty  Still a really confusing behaviour though 